# Does AndroidX BiometricPrompt APIs identify new faces registered in device?

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I am using AndroidX BiometricPrompt APIs to authenticate user to use my app using their registered fingerprint or face id.

As fingerprint authentication can be used with crypto object and secret key is stored for this fingerprint in keystore. And when new fingerprint registered the key gets invalidated and user will be prompted to register for biometric login again when he tries to login into the app.

Similar functionality I need to implement for Face ID authentication into app, but did not find anything related to identification of new face id registration in android device / API.

Request your inputs to implement new Face ID registration which will invalidate user login using Face ID and ask him to register again.

Thanks in advance.